# ¿Como solucionar el error no matching function for call to 'nodo::nodo(int&, nodo**)?

Tags: c++, funciones, parametros

Sé que el problema esta en los parametros (o al menos eso tengo entendido) ya que no los detecta como debería y en cada nodo es similar lo que busco es poder hacer un nodo para cada dato uno para  el nombre del trabajador otro para el puesto que lleva otro para su id la cosa esta que en esta linea soy nuevo en esto de la estructura de datos por lo que no entiendo aun con totalidad los conceptos puedo entender que es un parametro que es un arreglo y todo lo referenciado a Programacion orientada a objetos se me va uno que otro detalle aunque aun me cuenta entender ciertos terminos siempre los investigo para estar al tanto

```
nuevoA= new nodo(c, TopeA);
```

es la que me marca error

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class nodo {
   private:
    int cargo,obra,identificador;
    string nom,autor; 
    nodo *siguienteA;
    nodo *siguienteB;
    nodo *siguienteC;
    nodo *siguienteD;
    nodo *siguienteI;

   public:
    nodoI(int id, nodo*sigI=NULL){
        identificador=id;
        siguienteI=sigI;
       }
    nodoA(int c, nodo *sigA=NULL){
        cargo=c;
        siguienteA=sigA;
       }
    nodoB(int o, nodo*sigB=NULL){
        obra=o;
        siguienteB=sigB;
    }
    nodoC(string n,nodo *sigC = NULL) {
       nom=n;
       siguienteC = sigC;
    }
   
   nodoD(string a, nodo *sigD=NULL){
        autor =a;
        siguienteD=sigD;
   }
    
   friend class pila;
};

typedef nodo *pnodo, *pnodo1, *pnodo2, *pnodo3, *pnodo4;

class pila {
   private:
    pnodo TopeA;
    pnodo1 TopeB;
    pnodo2 TopeC;
    pnodo3 TopeD;
    pnodo4 TopeI;

   public:
    pila() : TopeA(NULL), TopeB(NULL),TopeC(NULL),TopeD(NULL),TopeI(NULL){}
    
    ~pila();
    void PushA(int c);
    void PushI(int id);
    void PushB(int o);
    void PushC(string n);
    void PushD(string a);
    int PopC();
    int PopD();
    int PopA();
    int PopI();
    int PopB();
};
 
pila::~pila() {
   while (TopeC) PopC();
   while (TopeA) PopA();
   while (TopeD) PopD();
   while (TopeI) PopI();
   while (TopeB) PopB();
}

void pila::PushA(int c){
    pnodo nuevoA;
    nuevoA= new nodo(c, TopeA);
    TopeA=nuevoA;
}
void pila::PushB(int o){
    pnodo1 nuevoB;
    nuevoB = new nodo(o, TopeB);
    TopeB=nuevoB;
}
void pila::PushI(int id){
    pnodo4 nuevoI;
    nuevoI=new nodo(id, TopeI);
    TopeI=nuevoI;
}
void pila::PushC(string n) {
   pnodo2 nuevoC;
   /* Crear un nodo nuevo */
   nuevoC = new nodo(n, TopeC);
   /* Ahora, el comienzo de nuestra pila es en nuevo nodo */
   TopeC = nuevoC;
}
void pila::PushD(string a) {
   pnodo3 nuevoD;
   
   /* Crear un nodo nuevo */
   nuevoD = new nodo(a, TopeD);
   /* Ahora, el comienzo de nuestra pila es en nuevo nodo */
   TopeD = nuevoD;
}

 string pila::PopC() {
   pnodo2 NodoAux; /* variable auxiliar para manipular nodo */
   string n;        /* variable auxiliar para retorno */
   
   if(!TopeC){cout << "Ya no hay" << endl; return 0;} /* Si no hay nodos en la pila retornamos 0 */
   /* Nodo apunta al primer elemento de la pila */
   NodoAux = TopeC;
   /* Asignamos a pila toda la pila menos el primer elemento */
   TopeC = NodoAux->siguiente;
   /* Guardamos el valor de retorno */
   n = NodoAux->nom; 
   /* Borrar el nodo */
   delete NodoAux;
   return n;
}
string pila::PopD() {
   pnodo3 NodoAux; /* variable auxiliar para manipular nodo */
   string a;        /* variable auxiliar para retorno */
   
   if(!TopeD){cout << "Ya no hay" << endl; return 0;} /* Si no hay nodos en la pila retornamos 0 */
   /* Nodo apunta al primer elemento de la pila */
   NodoAux = TopeD;
   /* Asignamos a pila toda la pila menos el primer elemento */
   TopeD = NodoAux->siguiente;
   /* Guardamos el valor de retorno */
   a = NodoAux->autor; 
   /* Borrar el nodo */
   delete NodoAux;
   return a;
}
int pila::PopA() {
   pnodo NodoAux; /* variable auxiliar para manipular nodo */
   int c;         /* variable auxiliar para retorno */
   
   if(!TopeA){cout << "Ya no hay" << endl; return 0;} /* Si no hay nodos en la pila retornamos 0 */
   /* Nodo apunta al primer elemento de la pila */
   NodoAux = TopeA;
   /* Asignamos a pila toda la pila menos el primer elemento */
   TopeA = NodoAux->siguiente;
   /* Guardamos el valor de retorno */
   c = NodoAux->cargo;
    
   /* Borrar el nodo */
   delete NodoAux;
   return c;
}
int pila::PopI() {
   pnodo4 NodoAux; /* variable auxiliar para manipular nodo */
   int id;         /* variable auxiliar para retorno */
   
   if(!Tope){cout << "Ya no hay" << endl; return 0;} /* Si no hay nodos en la pila retornamos 0 */
   /* Nodo apunta al primer elemento de la pila */
   NodoAux = TopeI;
   /* Asignamos a pila toda la pila menos el primer elemento */
   TopeI = NodoAux->siguiente;
   /* Guardamos el valor de retorno */
   id = NodoAux->identificador;
    
   /* Borrar el nodo */
   delete NodoAux;
   return id;
}
int pila::PopB() {
   pnodo1 NodoAux; /* variable auxiliar para manipular nodo */
   int o;         /* variable auxiliar para retorno */
   
   if(!Tope){cout << "Ya no hay" << endl; return 0;} /* Si no hay nodos en la pila retornamos 0 */
   /* Nodo apunta al primer elemento de la pila */
   NodoAux = TopeB;
   /* Asignamos a pila toda la pila menos el primer elemento */
   TopeB = NodoAux->siguiente;
   /* Guardamos el valor de retorno */
   o = NodoAux->obra;
    
   /* Borrar el nodo */
   delete NodoAux;
   return o;
}

int main() {
   pila Encargados,Pinturas;    
   int i,opcion,b, can,v;
   string a;
   while (opcion!=5){
   cout<<"\n \n \t******BIENVENIDO AL REGISTRO DE GALERIAS******\t\n\n"; 
   cout<<"\t SELECCIONE UNA OPCION \t"<<endl; 
   cout<<"\t1.Registrar encargados\n"<<endl; 
   cout<<"\t2.Registrar pinturas\n"<<endl;
   cout<<"\t3.mostrar registro de encargados\n"<<endl; 
   cout<<"\t4.mostrar registro de pinturas\n"<<endl;
   cout<<"\t5.Salir\n"<<endl; 
   cout<<"\n\n\t***OPCION***\t\n\n"<<endl; 
   cin>>opcion;
   fflush(stdin); 
        switch (opcion){
            case 1 :
             
                    cout<<"ingresa nombre del Encargados: \n"; 
                    getline(cin,a);
                    cout<<"cargo que desempeña: \n"; 
                    cin>>b;
                    fflush(stdin);
                    Encargados.Push(a,b);
                      
                 break;
            case 2 : 
                
                    cout<<"ingresa el nombre del autor de la Pinturas: \n"; 
                    getline(cin,a);
                    cout<<"ingresar el nombre de la obra: \n";
                    cin>>b;
                    Pinturas.PushP(a,b);
           break;
           case 3 : 
            cout<<"los registros en Encargados son: \n"<<endl;
                for (i=0;i<=2;i++){
                cout<<Encargados.Pop()<<endl;
                }break;
            case 4: 
             cout<<"los registros en Pinturas son: \n"<<endl;
                for (i=0;i<=2;i++){
                cout<<Pinturas.PopV()<<endl;
            }break;
            case 5: break;  
}
   cin.get();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

La clase `nodo` está mal implementada.

Los constructores son, junto con los destructores, las únicas funciones que no tienen valor de retorno. También son funciones cuyo valor no es libre, es decir, no puedes ponerle a un constructor el nombre que te de la gana. Un constructor tienen el mismo nombre que la clase.

Esto no es algo que se cumpla en tu caso:

```
class nodo {
   private:
    int cargo,obra,identificador;
    string nom,autor; 
    nodo *siguienteA;
    nodo *siguienteB;
    nodo *siguienteC;
    nodo *siguienteD;
    nodo *siguienteI;

   public:
    nodoI(int id, nodo*sigI=NULL){ // <<--- MAL
        identificador=id;
        siguienteI=sigI;
       }
    nodoA(int c, nodo *sigA=NULL){ // <<--- MAL
        cargo=c;
        siguienteA=sigA;
       }
    nodoB(int o, nodo*sigB=NULL){ // <<--- MAL
        obra=o;
        siguienteB=sigB;
    }
    nodoC(string n,nodo *sigC = NULL) { // <<--- MAL
       nom=n;
       siguienteC = sigC;
    }
   
   nodoD(string a, nodo *sigD=NULL){ // <<--- MAL
        autor =a;
        siguienteD=sigD;
   }
};
```

Por otro lado, vale, tienes 5 listas, pero cada lista es independiente de las demás. Todos los nodos de la lista A usan el puntero `siguienteA`, los de la lista B usan el puntero `siguienteB` y así.

Abstrayendo el problema, tu clase `nodo` no tiene ninguna necesidad especial que justifique el ser tan complicada. Tienes que gestionar 5 tipos diferentes de nodos, para eso necesitas crear una plantilla:

```
template<class T>
class nodo {
   private:
    T value; 
    nodo *siguiente;

   public:
    nodo(T value, nodo* sig=nullptr)
      : value{std::move(value)}
      , siguiente{sig}
    { }
    
    T const& GetValue() const
    { return value; }

   friend class pila;
};
```

Y ahora, ¿Cómo creamos las 5 listas?

Pues exactamente igual que ahora. Únicamente hay que adaptar los alias:

```
using nodoInt = nodo<int>;
using nodoString = nodo<string>;

class pila {
   private:
    nodoInt * TopeA;
    nodoInt * TopeB;
    nodoString * TopeC;
    nodoString * TopeD;
    nodoInt * TopeI;

   public:
    pila()
      : TopeA(nullptr)
      , TopeB(nullptr)
      , TopeC(nullptr)
      , TopeD(nullptr)
      , TopeI(nullptr)
    { }
    
    ~pila();
    void PushA(int c);
    void PushI(int id);
    void PushB(int o);
    void PushC(string n);
    void PushD(string a);

    string PopC();
    string PopD();
    int PopA();
    int PopI();
    int PopB();
};
 
pila::~pila() {
   while (TopeC) PopC();
   while (TopeA) PopA();
   while (TopeD) PopD();
   while (TopeI) PopI();
   while (TopeB) PopB();
}

void pila::PushA(int c){
    nodoInt * nuevoA = new nodoInt(c, TopeA);
    TopeA = nuevoA;
}

void pila::PushB(int o){
    nodoInt * nuevoB = new nodo(o, TopeB);
    TopeB = nuevoB;
}

void pila::PushI(int id){
    nodoInt * nuevoI = new nodo(id, TopeI);
    TopeI = nuevoI;
}

void pila::PushC(string n) {
   nodoString * nuevoC = new nodo(n, TopeC);
   TopeC = nuevoC;
}

void pila::PushD(string a) {
   nodoString * nuevoD = new nodo(a, TopeD);
   TopeD = nuevoD;
}

string pila::PopC() {
   if(!TopeC){cout << "Ya no hay" << endl; return "";}

   nodoString * aux = TopeC;
   TopeC = aux->siguiente;
   string n = aux->GetValue(); 

   delete aux;
   return n;
}

string pila::PopD() {
   if(!TopeD){cout << "Ya no hay" << endl; return "";}

   nodoString * aux = TopeD;
   TopeD = aux->siguiente;
   string n = aux->GetValue(); 

   delete aux;
   return n;
}

int pila::PopA() {
   
   if(!TopeA){cout << "Ya no hay" << endl; return 0;} /* Si no hay nodos en la pila retornamos 0 */

   nodoInt * aux = TopeA;

   TopeA = aux->siguiente;
   int c = aux->GetValue();
    
   delete aux;
   return c;
}

int pila::PopI() {
   if(!Tope){cout << "Ya no hay" << endl; return 0;}

   nodoInt * aux = TopeI;
   TopeI = aux->siguiente;
   int id = aux->GetValue();
    
   delete aux;
   return id;
}

int pila::PopB() {
   if(!Tope){cout << "Ya no hay" << endl; return 0;}

   nodoInt * aux = TopeB;
   TopeB = aux ->siguiente;
   int obra = aux ->GetValue();
    
   delete aux ;

   return obra;
}
```

De hecho, todas las llamadas `Pop` son ahora idénticas. Podríamos tener un método común para todas ellas:

```
class pila
{
    template<class T>
    T Pop(nodo<T> * &lista)
    {
        T to_return = {};

        if (lista != nullptr)
        {
            nodo<T> * aux = lista;
            lista = aux->siguiente;

            to_return = aux->GetValue();

            delete aux;
        }
        return to_return;
    }

public:
    int PopI()
    { return Pop(TopeI); }

    int PopA()
    { return Pop(TopeA); }

    int PopB()
    { return Pop(TopeB); }

    string PopC()
    { return Pop(TopeC); }

    string PopD()
    { return Pop(TopeD); }

};
```

Aunque lo suyo sería simplificar un poco más el proceso. Crear una clase `stack` que gestione únicamente una pila de datos para, a continuación, crear 5 stacks diferentes, pero eso ya te lo dejo a ti.